# Python class interface or inheritance

Tags: python

I am fairly new to python and I am a bit confused about the correct design of interfaces. I want different implementations for a single class.
AFAIK there are two ways to achieve this but I am not sure which one is the better way to go:
First approach: Using class inheritance in one file:
directory structure:

```
method
|--- __init__.py
|--- a.py
```

a.py:

```
class A(object):
    def do_sth(self):   pass

class A_imp1(A):
    def do_sth(self):   return 1

class A_imp2(A):
    def do_sth(self):   return 2
```

Usage:

```
from method.a import A_imp1, A_imp2
instance1 = A_imp1()
instance2 = A_imp2()
instance1.do_sth()
instance2.do_sth()
```

---

Second approach:
Directory structure:

```
method
|--- __init__.py
|--- a_int.py
|--- a_1.py
|--- a_2.py
```

a_int.py:

```
class A_interface(object):
    def do_sth(self):   pass
```

a_1.py:

```
from a_int import A_interface
class A(A_interface):
        def do_sth(self): return 1
```

a_2.py

```
from a_int import A_interface
class A(A_interface):
    def do_sth(self): return 2
```

Usage:

```
from method.a_1 import A as A_1
from method.a_2 import A as A_2
instance1 = A_1.A()
instance2 = A_2.A()
instance1.do_sth()
instance2.do_sth()
```

Which one (if any) is the correct pythonic way for achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to implement an [interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing))(Jump to section 4: Software interfaces in object-oriented languages) will be to use an abstract base class rather than a simple so that all the classes inheriting from it are enforced to implement their own methods:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = metaclass=ABCMeta

    @abstractmethod
    def do_sth(self):   pass

class A_imp1(A):
    def do_sth(self): return 1

class A_imp2(A):
    def do_sth(self): return 2
```

Now a user cannot initialize `A` on its own and any class inheriting from `A`, that doesn't defines its own `do_sth`, will fail to initialize as well:

```
>>> A()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    A()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A with abstract methods do_sth


>>> class A_imp3(A):
    pass

>>> a = A_imp3()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    a = A_imp3()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A_imp3 with abstract methods do_sth
```

With that said, I think both of your approaches look fine to me. It's basically how you would like to manage your classes. The [Python implementation of `io` module](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ea33b61cac74/Lib/_pyio.py#l277) in Python 3 has everything defined in a single place.

Answer (score 4):

Depends really, either are valid.

Say you're writing classes for employees, maybe you start off with

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

    def get_name(self):
        return self._name

    def get_position(self):
        return 'Not Hired'

class Employee(Person):
    def get_position(self):
        return 'Employee'

class Manager(Employee):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.employees = set()
        super(Manager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_position(self):
        return 'Manager'

    def manage(self, employee):
        self.employees.add(employee)
```

An employee will still have access to it's `get_name` method, but it will override the `get_position` method. Same thing for a manager.

Now, say you're writing a server

```
class BaseServer(object):
    def handle_request(self, request):
        raise NotImplementedError

class Server(BaseServer):
    def handle_request(self, request):
        ... do stuff ...
```

Here, you have an interface because you want to be sure any subclass will actually override your `handle_request` method.

Depending on what you're doing, either way could work.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this and I needed to thank you for the server example, since this is the perfect example of a use case for abstract classes that I've seen so far.